# Nightmarejs does not render javascript on server

Tags: nightmare

I'm using nightmare for scraping web page, which loads content by javascript after document.ready. I use the following code for receiving html content

```
.goto(URL)
.wait('.header--search-icon')
.evaluate(function () {
    let doc = document.querySelector('body').innerHTML;
    return doc;
}
```

When I execut this script on my local desctop everything is fine, I receive rendered html.
However, when I run it on server ubuntu 16.04 I receive javascript content which wasn't rendered.
I've installed electron and xvfb.
So, command
`DEBUG=nightmare:* xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" node index.js` works fine, but I receive javascript (not html) as a result.
How can I get result of rendered javascript?